# How to stretch flex child so that background color matches the height of sibling

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

I have two links in `li`, one with text which can be short or long, and the other is icon. The `background-color` of the icon should match the height of text link while text should have defined padding. It doesn't have to be flexbox, I just thought it should be easier.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GrQZKN

```
li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  .first {
    background-color: #333;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    flex: 1;
  }
  .second {
    background-color: orange;
    align-items: stretch;
    display: flex;
  }
}

<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="first">Link</a>
    <a href="#" class="second">(icon)</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="first">Longer LongerLonger Longer link</a>
    <a href="#" class="second">(icon)</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do the below:

1. Remove `align-items: center` from `li` (for *stretching* the `second`)
2. Replace `align-items: stretch` with `align-items: center` in `li.second` (for *vertical alignment*)

See demo below:

```css
body {
  max-width: 300px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  /*align-items: center;*/
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
li .first {
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  flex: 1;
}
li .second {
  background-color: orange;
  align-items: center; /*CHANGED THIS*/
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="first">Link</a>
    <a href="#" class="second">(icon)</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="first">Longer LongerLonger Longer link</a>
    <a href="#" class="second">(icon)</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```